# I have a tag within different layer, how can I make it to the same layer?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I am using python soup.

I have several `<div>` layers in my html, there is an id=page-break attribute in the inner `<div>` tag. Am I able to write a general code that I can get the `*<div>*` from the outer layer? All `*<div>*` are in parallel ie. they are in the same layer.

The div layer that contains id=page-break could be in the second inner layer or third inner layer. And there is no information that we can get from the `*<div>*` layer.

I don't want to get the div of the most outer one, but the one with asterisk which I listed as my example.

```
<div>
    *<div>*
        <div>
            <div id=page-break> asdf </div>
        </div>
    *</div>*
    
    *<div>*
        <div id=page-break> qwer </div>
    *</div>*
    *<div>*
        <div>
            <div id=page-break> asdf </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    *</div>*
    
</div>
```

Comment: So you want all `page-break`'s?

Comment: I need to get the `*<div>*` layer that has the <div id=page-break> in their children. And all the`*<div>*`  are in parallel. ie (same level layer)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right.

You can use CSS [`:root`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_root.asp) pseudo-class to reference the top-most `<div>` and then `:has(#page-break)` to get all `<div>` that conain the `id=page-break`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id=page-break> asdf </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id=page-break> qwer </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id=page-break> asdf </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for div in soup.select(":root > div:has(#page-break)"):
    print(div)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
<div>
<div>
<div id="page-break"> asdf </div>
</div>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div>
<div id="page-break"> qwer </div>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div>
<div>
<div id="page-break"> asdf </div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Or:

Select first `<div>` that contains `id=page-break` (in any level) and then use `:scope`:

```py
first_div = soup.select_one("div:has(#page-break)")

for div in first_div.select(":scope > div:has(#page-break)"):
    print(div)
    print("-" * 80)
```